# CCK Field Not Appearing in Row Array

Tags: theming

In Drupal 6, I added a custom field and attached it to a custom post type. I added sample articles and sample data in that custom post type. I added that custom field to a view. On individual articles, the custom field data shows up. But on a template that shows the five latest articles does not show the custom field.

I put this on that template:

```
<?php
 print '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($rows)) . '</pre>'; 
?>
```

And the custom field does not show in the array as it should.

This is the field I'm trying to show:

So is there somewhere else I need to activate this field? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use (display: node) you can check:

admin/content/node-type/{Your-Content-Type}/display

else if you use (display: fields) check you add it to fields.

Comment: I use node, and the display page is all set correctly. Any other ideas?